# Can't see the items when I print the list > frozenset({'nan'}

Tags: python-3.x, list, nan, apriori

I am trying to print the rules after using apriori. Instead of printing the actual items my code always prints `nan`.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from apyori import apriori
store_data = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\\\datasets\\popular_words_for_apriori.csv', header=None)
store_data.head()
num_records=len(store_data)
records = []
for i in range(0,99):
 records.append([str(store_data.values[i,j]) for j in range(0,54)])
association_rules = apriori(records, min_support=0.0053, min_confidence=0.2, min_lift=1, min_length=3)
association_results = list(association_rules)
print(association_results)
```

and this is the output:

```
[RelationRecord(items=frozenset({**'nan'**}), support=1.0, ordered_statistics=[OrderedStatistic(items_base=frozenset(), items_add=frozenset({'nan'}), confidence=1.0, lift=1.0)]), RelationRecord(items=frozenset({'**nan**', 'algorithm'}), support=0.010101010101010102
```

Comment: What does your CSV file look like?

Comment: @bernie contains words only, no numbers or header